# Binary search with bubble sort

Tags: c, binary-search, bubble-sort

Is it possible to have a binary search that uses a bubble sort to sort it?

This is my bubble sort and binary search.  How do I combine them?

```
int Search_for_Client (int cList[], int low, int high, int target) {
    int middle;
    while (low <= high) {
        middle = low + (high - low)/2;
        if (target < cList[middle])
            high = middle - 1;
        else if (target > cList[middle])
            low = middle + 1;
        else
            return middle;
    }
    return -1;
}

int bubbleSort(char cList[], int size) {
    int swapped;
    int p;
    for (p = 1; p < size; p++) {
        swapped = 0;    /* this is to check if the array is already sorted */
        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < size - p; j++) {
            if (cList[j] > cList[j+1]) {
                int temp = cList[j];
                cList[j] = cList[j+1];
                cList[j+1] = temp;
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }
        if (!swapped)
        {
            break; /*if it is sorted then stop*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *a linear search that uses a bubble sort to sort it*? Do you mean binary search?

Comment: Basically I need to combine a bubble sort and a linear search

Comment: Combine them into what?

Comment: That's not a linear search; it's a binary search.

Comment: That's what I meant, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, fix your code so it compiles.  For example, `bubbleSort` is declared as returning int but you don't return anything.

Then do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// *** paste your code here

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char data[11] = { 'z', 'y', 'x', 'w', 'v', 'u', 't', 's', 'r', 'q', 'p' };
    int foundIt;

    bubbleSort(data, 11);
    foundIt = Search_for_Client(data, 0, 10, 'w');
    if (foundIt >= 0)
       printf("Found 'w' at index %d\n", foundIt);
    else
       printf("Did not find 'w'\n");
}
```

Comment: Ok so I have a module for each of them then call them in main?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by having a module for them.  Do you mean a DLL?  If so, that's fine, but it's probably more complicated than you need right now.  The simplest way to do it is just paste the code you have into my example.  Paste your code before `main`. That way you have one simple file that should compile and run all by itself.

Comment: Ok, but this is apart of a larger program so changing [main] would mess up the whole program. I will try this though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use bubble sort to sort the array, and then use binary search on the resulting sorted array.

It is, however, worth noting that there are more efficient sorting methods than bubble sort.